# How to set multiple indexes

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric

I want to set multiple indexes.
Same as the sample below, I set multiple indexes by dividing attribute, but it is not vaild json.
Kindly let me know how to set multiple indexes correctly.

Sample at this link.
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/couchdb_tutorial.html

```
{
  "index":{
    "fields":["owner"] // Names of the fields to be queried
  },
  "ddoc":"index1Doc", // (optional) Name of the design document inwhich the index will be created.
  "name":"index1",
  "type":"json"
}
{
  "index":{
    "fields":["owner", "color"] // Names of the fields to be queried
  },
  "ddoc":"index2Doc", // (optional) Name of the design document inwhich the index will be created.
  "name":"index2",
  "type":"json"
}
{
 "index":{
   "fields":["owner", "color", "size"] // Names of the fields to bequeried
 },
 "ddoc":"index3Doc", // (optional) Name of the design document inwhich the index will be created.
 "name":"index3",
 "type":"json"
}
```

Comment: seems that you require to put this in different json files, one per index.

Comment: You can make multiple json files and use each index in three different files.

Comment: Don't use images of text. They're hard to read. They're _impossible_ for the visually impaired to read, and they can't be indexed. Just copy and paste the text instead.